# Mobile Access from Digitalocean apache2 connection timed out

Tags: apache, ubuntu-16.04, digital-ocean

I'm using Digitalocean cloud hosting server and apache2 in Ubuntu 16.04 VPS.  I can browse the site from my local PC and check apache access.log to see the page requests.  However when using a mobile device, I cannot get a response from the website.  I can ping the server IP address from my phone successfully.  However, any requests for the domain root do not create any record in the access.log.

I have attempted to uninstall fail2ban as per this threads:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-debug-solve-a-err_connection_timed_out-error-when-this-error-happens-on-some-browsers-but-not-in-another

http://installion.co.uk/ubuntu/vivid/universe/f/fail2ban/uninstall/index.html

I have also tried simply serving a phpinfo() page. However, no still no records in access.log when trying to access from mobile devices.  The site is has https enabled and is serving perfectly to a PC.

Also, using a browser testing site (https://www.browserstack.com/)  I also get connection timed out errors, and no response records in the access.log.

Any suggestions on where to start troubleshooting this?  Is this possibly a problem with Digitalocean itself? Is there anything in the LAMP stack that would specifically be blocking some browsers or IP addresses?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like one of two things is happening here:

1. Your DNS is not set to point to that IP, but you set it in your operating system's host file on your computer.
2. Your DNS is correct, but other systems are not yet seeing the change you've made.

Try visiting the IP of the server directly from your mobile device. If anything occurs besides timing out, be it a redirect (even if failed) or a page load, you will know that DNS resolution is the issue. Given that you can ping the IP from your phone I would suggest fail2ban is not related, as fail2ban should block ping as well.

If it turns out to be #2 there, it's just a game of waiting. DNS changes can take up to 48 hours to be seen by all systems. In most cases 4-6 hours is common, but 48 hours is still the recognized standard of "it could possibly take this long."

Jarland

Comment: When you said that failban was not the issue, I immediately thought of firewall, which I should checked.  Although allowing only port 443 works fine for all my browsers on Mac and Linux, but mobile devices are checking port 80 first when I use the url without https:// .  So, using www.site.com will use port 80.  Since I was routing everything to port 443, I had never even checked that port 80 was open, and in the end just opened port 80, then mobile browsers were routed properly to port 443 from there.  So, maybe mobile browsers check port 443 first by default and PC browsers check 443 first?